# Is there a build step in TeamCity that exits the build successfully without performing additional build steps?

Tags: teamcity

I have a project that needs to execute either three or four build steps depending on the branch in source control.  More specifically, if I'm merging in a PR and running the build (for GitHub status notifications) I have one extra build step that is required.

It's that last build step that I need to omit if it's a non-PR branch.

Is there a way to add a build step that checks the trigger and exits the build successfully? Or a way to exclude a build step based on a branch filter?

Answer (score 1):

You can check the condition and modify the step logic inside the build script. See the [related ticket](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-17939) and an [example](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/TW-17939#comment=27-1273143) of the script.
BTW, It is not a good practice to change the logic of the build inside build script. In this case you no longer "compare" builds in the build configuration: they start to form multiple unrelated sequences. Also the statistics of the builds will be uninformative. The recommended setup is to create several build configurations based on [template](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/Build+Configuration+Template).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on which type of runner you are launching, but you can, in some cases, add few lines of code to get your current branch name with the property : `%teamcity.build.branch%`

In my case, I just add this as an extra parameter for powershell scripts and if this is a number, do something, else, do other stuff. ;)